# Intern WebDriver and PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs, intern

I've written my main unit tests while testing in the browser (client.html), and now I'm ready to setup test automation through Node, however I don't have a Selenium server setup yet, and management will probably never give the okay to use a third party service like Sauce Labs, so I'm trying to run Intern test through PhantomJS using it's webdriver mode.

I'm running PhantomJS with these options:

```
$ phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false --webdriver=8910
```

My Intern configuration looks like this:

```
define({
  proxyPort: 9000,
  proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
  environments: [
    {
      browserName: 'phantom',
      version: '1.9.0',
      platform: 'Linux'
    }
  ],
  webdriver: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8910
  },
  maxConcurrency: 3,
  useSauceConnect: false,
  // ...
});
```

It seems to work for the most part, however my I am having issues with AJAX requests in my tests. Since tests are run through Intern's own server, I've added an AJAX filter to make sure requests are sent to the correct place:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
  options.url = serverName + options.url;
});
```

I'm still finding that my AJAX requests are failing however. Upon further inspection I've found that the requests aren't being sent (AJAX fails with a `readyState` of 0). PhantomJS doesn't seem to provide any more information than this. The `--web-security=false` flag for `phantomjs` should ensure that cross-domain requests are possible, so I'm unsure of the cause.

No specific error is thrown in PhantomJS, the only information given to the fail handler is a status of "error".

**EDIT:**
I've tried doing a manual XMLHttpRequest without jQuery, and it works successfully. So clearly this is something on jQuery's end. Enabling the `crossDomain` doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

So, for reasons I haven't quite figured out yet, using `method` instead of `type` in the AJAX config resolved the issue (I stumbled upon that by accident). I can't quite see why, since `method` is just an alias for `type` in jQuery:

```
s.type = options.method || options.type || s.method || s.type;
```

Regardless, this did fix the issue for me.